# Disable activity that starts another activity

Tags: android, popup, android-activity

I have a popup which I implement with an activity, e.i the activity doesn't fill the whole screen, and looks like a popup.

How can I disable the caller activity? (The background activity).

I want the same functionality as if I used a classic popup:

```
popup.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you want to call disable activity. I think no need to call it.

Comment: Because my caller is an activity and my "popup" (callee) is implemented as an activity.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an activity with

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen".
```

There add your view over the transparent activity like a popup.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me. I need just to diable the caller activity :/

Comment: then may be i misunderstood your question? can you please describe the scenario more clearly

Comment: 2 activities A,B. A preform startActivity(new intent(B.class));
I want A will be disable from B. Don't forget that B's xml is not full screen so A still visible from B.

Comment: ok .. Then i understood you correctly. I just suggested to create B as transparent. So when you click the transparent part then the previous activity is not trigerred